# Save extension attribute without plugin

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I have created an `extension_attribute` for "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface".

Have a custom table to save that `extension_attribute`.

How I can save the `extension_attribute` attribute to a custom table without a plugin?

checked [Adobe Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html) but is saving data using a plugin

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you please add why you don't want to add it via plugin?

Comment: @VivekKumar due to requirement, I need to save data from a custom model/block class.

Comment: You can inject the model/block class in the plugin as well. Just saying, plugin is the standard method of implementing this.